# Using C# generics for discrete types with similar properties

Tags: c#, generics

I have 4 C# `DataSets` with almost identical properties. Specifically, many of the properties are the same names and types.  However, I cannot easily abstract them to a super class because the `DataSets` are auto-generated from `XML schema` using the '`XSD`' program, and they will need to be regenerated if the schema ever changes.
The DataSets are also very complicated (14000 lines of code each).

I would to write some common routines that only use the properties in common.  Is there a way of doing this?

Here are some ideas so far, non ideal:

1. Use generics? Not possible I think because the where clause would
   have to account for 4 alternative types?
2. Add interfaces? Possible, but a bit of a pain to create and manage.
3. Reflection?  Not attractive.

Comment: interfaces is probably the best option. If the schema changes, yeah you have to re-write things. Probably the compiler will help you, also hopefully will the documentation telling you what's changed. If you want the convenience of sharing some methods in common (provided by implementing an interface across all the types) you have to accept the maintenance overhead which goes along with it.

Comment: I would consider writing a wrapper class for each of the DataSet classes and have the wrapper implement a common interface. The wrapper class would do nothing more than delegate any calls to the real dataset class. It will require maintenance when you have to update the generated datasets but the rest of your code using the wrapper should be protected from constant change.

Comment: Another (nasty) option is to write a wrapper class that have the common properties and that holds exactly one object of one of the 4 classes. When you call the getters of the properties, the wrapper class returns the value from the object that is attached to the class.

Comment: Use a generic class with dynamic linq ?

Comment: `partial class` perhaps? How are the classes generated? If it's T4, can you modify the T4 templates?

Comment: If have power over the XML schema, you can use extended types. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I went for interfaces in the end.  It is a fair amount of work, as I am already up to 20 interfaces, and not finished yet.  I am still in two minds whether a late-binding approach might have been better, picking out the data using strings rather than strong typing.

For anyone coming across this in the future, I have a hint which makes the interface approach more acceptable.  In my first attempt I couldn't get the inheritance definition to work in a partial class, so I was editing the generated DataSet classes directly to add the 20 interface inheritance statements to each one.  This was going to be a problem when the class was regenerated.  However, I have now discovered the problem was because of class nesting, and it can all be done in a separate file, with no changes to the auto-generated class file.

Here is a specific example for anyone who needs one:

```
namespace GvResults // namespace for this auto-generated DataSet
{
    public partial class NewDataSet     // Main class in the auto-generated DataSet
    {
        public partial class ResultSetRow : ResultSetDataFns.IResultSetRow { }      // Add interface inheritance to a nested class in the auto-generated DataSet
        public partial class RiskRecordRow : ResultSetDataFns.IRiskRecordRow { }
        // ...etc...
    }
}
```